# Returning Data from JSON Parse - Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

So I'm a newbie with Swift, and somewhat with programming in general.  I've only been doing it since the first of the year...  I'm trying to make a simple app that pulls data from an external JSON file, and inputs it into UILabels.  I've gotten the data to pull, and append to an array.  From here, it seems to exit the scope and not be useable anywhere else...  I've created a struct that is to hold the data, accordingly.  As you can see, I've added print markers to see what is going on, visually.

```
  struct GlobalTestimonialData {
        var testimonialsText: [String]
        var customerNames: [String]
        var companyNames: [String]
    }

    var TestimonialData = GlobalTestimonialData(testimonialsText: [""], customerNames: [""], companyNames: [""])

    func getData () {
        let requestURL: URL = URL(string: "https://szadydesigns.com/test/mobileapp/testimonials.php")!
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL as URL) 
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

    if (statusCode == 200) {
                print("File has been downloaded!")
                do {

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments)

                    print("JSON Serialized")

                    if let JSONfile = json as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        print("JSON Reading")
                        if let testimonial = JSONfile["testimonial"] as? [String] {
                            print("Testimonials Read")
                            TestimonialData.testimonialsText.append(contentsOf: testimonial)
                            print(TestimonialData.testimonialsText)
                            print("Inside of loop Testimonial Text Number: \(TestimonialData.testimonialsText.count)")

                            if let name = JSONfile["name"] as? [String] {
                                print("Names Read")
                                TestimonialData.customerNames.append(contentsOf: name)
                                print(TestimonialData.customerNames)
                                print("Inside of loop Customers Number: \(TestimonialData.customerNames.count)")
                            }
                            if let company = JSONfile["company"] as? [String] {
                                print("Companies Read")
                                TestimonialData.companyNames.append(contentsOf: company)
                                print(TestimonialData.companyNames)
                            }
                            print("Companies: \(TestimonialData.companyNames)")
                        }
                        print("COMPANIES: \(TestimonialData.companyNames)")
                    }
                    print("Companies AGIAN: \(TestimonialData.companyNames)")
                }catch {
                    print("Error with Json: \(error)")
                }
                print("Companies AGIAN AGAIN : \(TestimonialData.companyNames)")
            }
            print("Companies AGIAN AGAIN AGAIN: \(TestimonialData.companyNames)")
        }

        //Loses Scope
        print("Companies AGIAN TIMES : \(TestimonialData.companyNames)")
        task.resume()

        print("Outside of loop Customers Number: \(TestimonialData.customerNames.count)")
        print("Outside of loop Testimonial Text Number: \(TestimonialData.testimonialsText.count)")
        print(TestimonialData.companyNames)
    }
```

I know I'm missing something really simple...but I'm at a loss...  Any help/info is appreciated!

Comment: Are you using a Storyboard? Your code is not within any custom class which you'd link to a storyboard, so I'm confused as to how you are going to display the data.

Comment: You are missing to call the callback, the print lines after `task.resume()` will always print *no data* because `dataTask` works asynchronously. There is another big design mistake in your code: A custom struct is supposed to create **one** instance for **each** testimonial rather then holding multiple arrays. And in Swift 3 use native `URL`, `URLRequest` and `[String:Any]` for a JSON dictionary.

Comment: Yes, I am using a Storyboard.  The above code is in it's own .Swift file, to keep the ViewController 'clean'.

Comment: your problem is the `requestURL`, it seems there is some issue with the endpoint, is it your private endpoint, or public. if public i was not able to have access to it... The thing is if the endpoint is not good, your json data will always be nil that's why you could not update your `struct`... so double check your endpoint

Comment: Lamar, how do I set my 'endpoint'?  Sorry if I seem lost here...I really am.  If I throw all of the current code in the viewController, everything seems to work.  I just don't want to set it up this way because it's insanely messy (and I'm sure it is NOT the way to do it...).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with this code:

First: The JSON you are receiving is not in the format your code expects. The root object isn't a dictionary but an array.

```
if let JSONfile = json as? [String: Any] {
```

changes to

```
if let JSONfile = json as? [[String: String]] {
```

This also requires you to loop over each item.

```
print("JSON Reading")
for item in JSONfile {
```

As the dictionary definition has changed from `[String:Any]` to `[String:String]` the `as? String` statements are no longer needed either.

Second: I'm not sure if you realise this or not (maybe you already do) but the bits of code after the `//Loses Scope` line run *first*. Before the `Companies AGIAN AGAIN` and `Companies AGIAN AGAIN AGAIN` lines.

They might be further down the page but the lines above that are in a closure that runs after the file has downloaded and so execute later after the other lines have already run.

---

Here is the complete fixed code (formatted in such a way you can copy and paste it into an Xcode Playground to see it working).

```
// Xcode 8.2, Swift 3
import Cocoa
import PlaygroundSupport

// Required for the download to work.
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true


struct GlobalTestimonialData {
    var testimonialsText: [String]
    var customerNames: [String]
    var companyNames: [String]
}

var testimonialData = GlobalTestimonialData(testimonialsText: [], customerNames: [], companyNames: [])

func getData () {
    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://szadydesigns.com/test/mobileapp/testimonials.php")!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL as URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            print("File has been downloaded!")
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments)

                print("JSON Serialized")

                if let JSONfile = json as? [[String: String]] {
                    print("JSON Reading")
                    for item in JSONfile {
                        if let testimonial = item["testimonial"] {
                            testimonialData.testimonialsText.append(testimonial)

                            if let name = item["name"] {
                                testimonialData.customerNames.append(name)
                            }
                            if let company = item["company"] {
                                testimonialData.companyNames.append(company)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")
            }
        }
        print("Companies Last: \(testimonialData.companyNames)")
        print(" ")
        print(testimonialData)
    }

    //Loses Scope
    print("Companies 1 : \(testimonialData.companyNames)")
    task.resume()

    print("Before the download of the JSON Customer names count: \(testimonialData.customerNames.count)")
    print("Before the download of the JSON Testimonial Text Number: \(testimonialData.testimonialsText.count)")
    print(testimonialData.companyNames)
}

getData()
```

And you will get this output, which helps explain what is going on (though I removed the actual company names).

```
Companies 1 : []
Before the download of the JSON Customer names count: 0
Before the download of the JSON Testimonial Text Number: 0
[]
File has been downloaded!
JSON Serialized
JSON Reading
Companies: ["REMOVED_1", "REMOVED_2", "REMOVED_3", "REMOVED_4"]
```